# Random crash on ABAddressBookSave

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook

I am having a problem solving a random crash: It some times crashes/ sometimes not. According to [EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executing ABAddressBookSave !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494830/exc-bad-access-when-executing-abaddressbooksave), I should take multivalueref for proper values,

date, address, email, phone: all have been taken as multiValueRef.

code for reference:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABRecordRemoveValue (record,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonPrefixProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonSuffixProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonNicknameProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonDepartmentProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonJobTitleProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonNoteProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonBirthdayProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonAddressProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonEmailProperty,&error);
ABRecordRemoveValue(record,kABPersonPhoneProperty,&error);
bool success = false;

string  m_strDisplayName = item->getDisplayName();
string m_strFirstName = item->getFirstName();
string m_strLastName = item->getLastName();
string m_strMiddleName = item->getMiddleName();
string m_strAddress = item->getAddress();
string m_strHomeAddr = item->getHomeAddress();
string m_strWorkAddress = item->getWorkAddress();
string m_strCompany = item->getCompany();
string m_strTitle = item->getTitle();
string m_strPhoto = item->getPhoto();
string m_strNotes = item->getNotes();
string m_strPrefix = item->getPrefix();
string m_strSuffix = item->getSuffix();
string m_strNickName = item->getNickName();
string m_strDepartment = item->getDepartment();
string m_strBirthDay = item->getBirthDay();
string m_strAnniversary = item->getAnniversary();
CFStringRef c1 = NULL;
CFStringRef c2 = NULL;
CFStringRef c3 = NULL;
CFStringRef c4 = NULL;
CFStringRef c5 = NULL;
CFStringRef c6 = NULL;
CFStringRef c7 = NULL;
CFStringRef c8 = NULL;
CFStringRef c9 = NULL;
CFStringRef c10 = NULL;
NSDateComponents *components1 = nil;
NSDateComponents *components2  = nil;
if (m_strBirthDay.length()!=0) {
    U_STRING bdayyear =m_strBirthDay.substr (0,4);
    U_STRING bdaymonth = m_strBirthDay.substr(4,2);
    U_STRING bdayday = m_strBirthDay.substr(6, 2);
    components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components1 setDay:STRING_TO_INT(bdayday)]; 

    [components1 setMonth:STRING_TO_INT(bdaymonth)]; 
    [components1 setYear:STRING_TO_INT(bdayyear)];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *bday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components1];
    c10 = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,m_strBirthDay.c_str(),kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty,bday, &error);
}
if (m_strAnniversary.length()!=0) {
    U_STRING anniyear =m_strAnniversary.substr (0,4);
    U_STRING annimonth = m_strAnniversary.substr(4,2);
    U_STRING anniday = m_strAnniversary.substr(6, 2);
    components2 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components2 setDay:STRING_TO_INT(anniday)];

    [components2 setMonth:STRING_TO_INT(annimonth)]; 
    [components2 setYear:STRING_TO_INT(anniyear)];
    NSCalendar *gregorian1 = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                              initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *anni = [gregorian1 dateFromComponents:components2];
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiDate = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonDateProperty);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiDate,anni,kABPersonAnniversaryLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonDateProperty, multiDate,&error);
}


if(m_strPhoto.length()!=0)
{
    CFDataRef pho  = CFDataCreate( NULL, (const UInt8*) m_strPhoto.data(), m_strPhoto.size() );
     ABPersonSetImageData (record,pho,&error);  
}



    string chome=m_strHomeAddr;
string cwork=m_strWorkAddress;
NSString *nhome,*nwork;
nhome=[[NSString alloc]initWithCString:chome.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
nwork=[[NSString alloc]initWithCString:cwork.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *ahome = [nhome componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSArray *awork = [nwork componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary  = nil;

 ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress =ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);


if([ahome count]>=2 &&([[ahome objectAtIndex:2] length] !=0 ||[[ahome objectAtIndex:3] length] !=0 ||[[ahome objectAtIndex:4] length] !=0 ||[[ahome objectAtIndex:5] length] !=0 ||[[ahome objectAtIndex:6] length] !=0 ))
{

   addressDictionary  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



    if([[ahome objectAtIndex:2] length] !=0){
[addressDictionary setObject:[ahome objectAtIndex:2] forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        }
    if([ahome count]>3 && [[ahome objectAtIndex:3] length] !=0){
[addressDictionary setObject:[ahome objectAtIndex:3] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
        }
    if([ahome count]>4 && [[ahome objectAtIndex:4] length] !=0){
[addressDictionary setObject:[ahome objectAtIndex:4] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
        }
    if([ahome count]>5 && [[ahome objectAtIndex:5] length] !=0){
[addressDictionary setObject:[ahome objectAtIndex:5] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
    }
    if([ahome count]>6 && [[ahome objectAtIndex:6] length] !=0){

[addressDictionary setObject:[ahome objectAtIndex:6] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
        }

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
 }
NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary1 = nil;
if([awork count]>=2&&([[awork objectAtIndex:2] length] !=0 ||[[awork objectAtIndex:3] length] !=0 ||[[awork objectAtIndex:4] length] !=0 ||[[awork objectAtIndex:5] length] !=0 ||[[awork objectAtIndex:6] length] !=0 ))
{

    addressDictionary1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if([[awork objectAtIndex:2] length] !=0)
    [addressDictionary1 setObject:[awork objectAtIndex:2] forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    if([[awork objectAtIndex:3] length] !=0)
    [addressDictionary1 setObject:[awork objectAtIndex:3] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    if([[awork objectAtIndex:4] length] !=0)
    [addressDictionary1 setObject:[awork objectAtIndex:4] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
    if([[awork objectAtIndex:5] length] !=0)
    [addressDictionary1 setObject:[awork objectAtIndex:5] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
    if([[awork objectAtIndex:6] length] !=0)
    [addressDictionary1 setObject:[awork objectAtIndex:6] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];


    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary1, kABWorkLabel, NULL);

}
success = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress,&error);
if (addressDictionary) [addressDictionary release];
if (addressDictionary1) [addressDictionary1 release];


     //setting Emails
vector<U_STRING> emails = item->getEmails();
vector<U_UINT32> emailAttrs = item->getEmailAttrs();
NSString *em = NULL;
CFStringRef c1pe = NULL;
string s="Primary Email";
c1pe=CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,s.c_str(),kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
if (emails.size()>0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++) {
        string attr = "";
        string email =emails.at(i);
        if (email.length() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        em = [NSString stringWithCString:email.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];          
        int emailAttr = emailAttrs.at(i);

        if ((emailAttr & item->ATTR_HOME) != 0) {
            attr += ";HOME";
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, em, kABHomeLabel, NULL);

        }
        else if ((emailAttr & item->ATTR_WORK) != 0) {
            attr += ";WORK";
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, em, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        }


        else if ((emailAttr & item->ATTR_NONE) != 0) {
            attr += ";OTHER";
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, em, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
        }
        else {

            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail,em,c1pe, NULL);
        }

    }

    ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail,&error);

}



//setting Phones
vector<U_STRING> phoneNumbers = item->getPhoneNumbers();
vector<U_UINT32> phoneNumberAttrs = item->getPhoneNumberAttrs();
NSString *ph = NULL;
CFStringRef c1hp = NULL;
c1hp=CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,s.c_str(),kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFStringRef c1wp = NULL;
c1wp=CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,s.c_str(),kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
if (phoneNumbers.size()>0) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.size(); i++) {
        string attr = "";
        string phoneNumber =phoneNumbers.at(i);

        if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        ph=[NSString stringWithCString:phoneNumber.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        int phoneAttr = phoneNumberAttrs.at(i);
        if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_PAGER) != 0) {
            attr += ";PAGER";
            if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_HOME) != 0) {
                attr += ";HOME";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhonePagerLabel, NULL);

            }else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_WORK) != 0) {
                attr += ";WORK";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhonePagerLabel, NULL);
            }
        }
        else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_FAX) != 0) {
            attr += ";FAX";
            if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_HOME) != 0) {
                attr += ";HOME";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel, NULL);


            }else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_WORK) != 0) {
                attr += ";WORK";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel, NULL);


            }
        }
        else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_MOBILE) != 0) {
            attr += ";CELL";
            if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_HOME) != 0) {
                attr += ";HOME";
                string s="Mobile (Home)";

                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,c1hp, NULL);
            }else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_WORK) != 0) {
                attr += ";WORK";
                string s="Mobile (Work)";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,c1wp, NULL);
            }
            else {
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
            }


        }
        else {
            attr += ";VOICE";
            if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_HOME) != 0) {
                attr += ";HOME";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph, kABHomeLabel, NULL);

            }else if ((phoneAttr & item->ATTR_WORK) != 0) {
                attr += ";WORK";
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph, kABWorkLabel, NULL);

            }
            else {
                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,ph,kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
            }

        }
    }
 ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,&error);
}

//saving to address book
if(ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, record, &error)){
        success = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);//EXC_BAD_EXCESS only sometimes(may be only for some contacts or their property. I am not sure)
    if (error !=NULL) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
    }
    }
```

NOTE: On scrutinizing more, I found that ABAddressBookSave is where the thread running is stuck whereas there is a crash on some other thread, please refer the stack trace below:
[image]

But this is not the same always.

Can anyone find what is wrong with this code? Please help.

**EDIT:** I commented all the code in this method, and just wrote:

```
 if(ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, record, &error)){
        success = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);//EXC_BAD_EXCESS 
    if (error !=NULL) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
    }
    }
```

and it is still crashing with bt:
[image]

I am suspecting this is some **Thread** issue. If anyone knowledgable can comment and confirm this, will be of great help!

Comment: does your app has access of user contacts ? Does your code seeks for users permissions ?

Comment: What is the purpose of attr variable ? You do a strange addition on it.

Comment: @VincentZgueb that's just a variable..and addition is of Defined int MACROS

Comment: @yunas: ofcourse, else, i will get addressbook as nil on abaddressbookcreate

Comment: Do you have a separate addressBook reference for the thread that tries to save your changes? If not, this might cause random errors, since you cannot pass addressBook references across multiple threads.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner For that,I have used NSLock to give access to the addressbook instance only to the one using right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the problem:
There was some C++ code that was creating a problem.I was using `strcpy(str1, str2)` function where the string had special charters and thus was not ending with /0. Using `strncpy(str1,str2,len)` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code I don't see any where you have seek for users permission 
You can ask user for his/her permission to allow you app to access the contacts as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6/12838224#12838224)